# Graphics corrupted on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: drivers, hardware, 14.10

I currently have **Ubuntu 14.10** installed on my PC. Previously I used Windows 7 and never experienced such things. I haven't figured out what triggers it, but most of the time the visual appearance is just normal. Usually a reboot helps, but I'd like to know what is really happening.
Since I have no reputation yet, I cannot upload pictures. Please follow the link to the images on my Google Drive.
[Images of the visual problem.](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1cZZXb4N-rmNnFNUWRVcVU5Q2M&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like graphics card malfunction, possibly due to overheating. It can be operating system dependent - just Windows driver manages GPU fan(s) better than Linux one. It also may be faulty driver - it is not uncommon in a Linux world. Please add more details about your hardware - what GPU chip do you use, is any proprietary drivers available in *Additional Drivers* etc.